# Removing duplicates based on 2 columns but keeping the row where the 3rd column is not null

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset that has some duplicates in the name and date, however the 3rd column has a number or null value, when removing the duplicate I want to make the condition to keep the not null value in the 3rd column

example:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFlOW.png)

I want to keep all the ones that are in blue, so as you can see it isnt that I want to get rid of all the null values. and if i highlight the date and name column and remove duplicates it keeps first, and there is no pattern as to whether the number shows as first or second in the duplicates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
library(gdata)

your.data <- tibble(
    Name = c("Wanita Jones" , "Wanita Jones", "Corbin Dallas", "Corbin Dallas", "Corbin Dallas", "Corbin Dallas", "Alex Mills", "Alex Mills", "Andrea Coyle", "Andrea Coyle"),
    Date = c("01/24/2021"   , "01/24/2021", "03/28/2021", "03/28/2021", "03/29/2021", "03/31/2021", "01/24/2021", "01/24/2021", "03/27/2021", "04/01/2021"),
    Request = c("null"      , 6, 7, "null", "null", 1, "null", 10, "null", "null")
)

your.data %>% filter(
    !duplicated2(interaction(Name,Date)) | Request != "null"
)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Name          Date       Request
  <chr>         <chr>      <chr>  
1 Wanita Jones  01/24/2021 6      
2 Corbin Dallas 03/28/2021 7      
3 Corbin Dallas 03/29/2021 null   
4 Corbin Dallas 03/31/2021 1      
5 Alex Mills    01/24/2021 10     
6 Andrea Coyle  03/27/2021 null   
7 Andrea Coyle  04/01/2021 null
```

If you have no interest in installing `gdata`, you can first sort on Request you make sure the first item of a duplicate is always the one without null:

```r
your.data %>% arrange( Request == "null" ) %>%
    filter(
        !duplicated(interaction(Name,Date)) | Request != "null"
    ) %>% arrange( Date, Name )
```

Or just paste the function from the [source](https://rdrr.io/rforge/gdata/src/R/duplicated2.R)